# Log to different files with nlog

Tags: c#, .net, nlog, masstransit, topshelf

I'm trying to log to different files using Nlog. For now i'm logging to two different files, one for application, second for Topshelf and Masstransit. In my app i initializing my logger like  this 
`LogManager.GetLogger("MyLogger");`

which is configured in Nlog.config.

This is Masstransit and Topshelf logging configured

```
NLogLogger.Use();
HostLogger.UseLogger(new NLogLogWriterFactory.NLogHostLoggerConfigurator());
```

How could i configure Topshelf and Masstransit 3 to use different Nlog loggers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a `LogFactory` to MassTransit in the configuration:

```
Bus.Factory.CreateUsingXxx(x => x.UseNLog(logFactory));
```

That `LogFactory` can be created using a separate NLog configuration.